# Many-to-many (belongsToMany) Laravel relation doesn't seem to work under HHVM

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, many-to-many, relationships

MySQL tables:
posts
tags
post_tag (with columns post_id and tag_id)

```
// Post.php model
class Post extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'posts';
    public $timestamps = true;

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Tag');
    }
}

// Tag.php model
class Tag extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'tags';
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Post');
    }
}

// on routes.php
Route::get('/', function()
{
    $post = Post::find(44);
    echo $post . '<br>';

    $tag = Tag::find(28);
    echo $tag;

    return $post->tags;
});
```

when hitting / it prints post:44, it prints tag:28 and gives

> ErrorException Cannot use a scalar value as an array

when accessing tags property that is on Post.php tags() function.
bare in mind that on post_tag's table there's an entry with post_id=44 and tag_id=28 but it could be empty.
Laravel/php gives me that error while trying to access the belongsToMany('Tag') method.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've been further researching the problem into the framework's code an found that if I instead right the relation like this, it works:

public function tags()
 {
  return $this->belongsToMany('Tag', null, null, null, 'anything-in-here-not-null');
 }

Comment: Hey, is HHVM ready for prime time yet ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be fixed on February update: http://www.hhvm.com/blog/3287/hhvm-2-4-0

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use eager loading:

```
$post = Post::with('tag')->find(28);
```

I don't have a laravel setup in front of me to test. So `find` might not be chainable, so you might need to do this:

```
$post = Post::with(array('tag' => function($query)
{
    $query->where('id', '=', 44);
}))->get();
```

Comment: this was an HHVM problem. this is plain many-to-many in Laravel. should work out of the box. i forgot i was using hhvm and not php. it happens not to work with everything as of right now.